# using libcluttermm-1.0 problem

Tags: gtk, gtkmm, clutter

i have installed clutter-1.0 from gnome site using terminal.

But when i run the application, error is notified as libcluttermm-1.0 not found. Has this

library not available as of now. if not what is the alternative that i can use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use libclutter instead, as libcluttermm is not in Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: ... but why is libcluttermm not there?

Answer (score 0):

What did you install exactly?  libcluttermm (C++ interface to Clutter) is provided by the cluttermm package. On my Fedora system, I ran:

```
# yum install cluttermm
# locate libcluttermm
/usr/lib/libcluttermm-1.0.so.0
/usr/lib/libcluttermm-1.0.so.0.0.0
```

Of course, if you are doing development against it install cluttermm-devel instead.

Comment: In Ubuntu repository, libcluttermm is void, so that is the main problem. Rather using libcluttermm use libclutter only.